# How to get the top record group wise in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a student table and enrollment table. Each student can have more than one enrollment, but only one current enrollment. If I want to get the current enrollment of a student, I have to select the top enrollment record for that student.

Example query:

```
select top 1 enrollmentid
from enrollmenttable 
where enrollmenttable.studentid = studentid
order by enrollmenttable.enrolldate desc
```

The above query returns the current enrollment for one student. I want to modify the above query, so that I can retrieve the current enrollment for multiple students. I.e. I want to select top 1 record for multiple student id's.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to be sorting your data explicitly in your query. My preference would be something like this;

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #EnrolmentData (StudentID int, EnrolmentID int)
INSERT INTO #EnrolmentData (StudentID, EnrolmentID)
VALUES
(1,1001)
,(1,1002)
,(2,1003)
,(3,1004)
,(3,1005)
,(3,1006)
```

Actual Query

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        StudentID
        ,EnrolmentID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentID, EnrolmentID) RowNum
        FROM #EnrolmentData
    ) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1
```

Result;

```
StudentID   EnrolmentID RowNum
1           1001        1
2           1003        1
3           1004        1
```

You can run the inner query on it's own to see what it's doing (once you've made the temp table). You haven't mentioned what data types you're working with so you'll want to make sure that you're ordering by the correct fields. If you want the highest number EnrolmentID (and the field is an int) then just stick a `DESC` after it within the subquery.

Query with DESC

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        StudentID
        ,EnrolmentID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentID, EnrolmentID DESC) RowNum
        FROM #EnrolmentData
    ) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1
```

Result

```
StudentID   EnrolmentID RowNum
1           1002        1
2           1003        1
3           1006        1
```

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to upvote any answers that were helpful and mark one as accepted if it has solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer apply`:

```
select e.*
from students s outer apply
     (select top 1 e.*
      from enrollments e
      where e.studentid = s.studentid
      order by enrollmentid desc
     ) e;
```

Note that your query uses `TOP` without `ORDER BY`.  This is a bad habit -- it returns an arbitrary row that might even change on different executions.  In general, always use `ORDER BY` with `TOP` unless you really, really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for the desired result .

```
WITH cte_enrollment
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY enrolldate desc) AS RNO ,
   studentid,enrollmentid,enrolldate 
FROM student s
 JOIN enrollmenttable e
            ON e.studentid = s.studentid
)

SELECT  studentid,enrollmentid,enrolldate 
FROM cte_enrollment
WHERE RNO=1
```